# Compare the proportions of a (somewhat) same sample before and after intervention

Tags: statistical-significance, missing-data, proportion, paired-data

I had a sample of 28 subjects. I surveyed all of them before an intervention and found that the proportion of them showing agreement on a question was 0.86. Unfortunately, 3 of them didn't participate in the survey conducted after the intervention, which brought the sample size down to 25. I surveyed the 25 subjects again anyway using the same questionnaire and the result showed that the proportion of the subjects that agreed on the exact same question increased to 0.96. The survey was anonymous, so I couldn't match the subjects.

In short:

Before intervention: n1 = 28, n(agreed) = 24, p1 = 0.86

After intervention (same sample but 3 dropped out): n2 = 25, n(agreed) = 24, p2 = 0.96

In this case, what method should I use to test the statistical significance? Any help will be appreciated!